# using navigator geolocation with reactors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation

I'm trying to display geolocation variables `position.coords.lat/long` and I'm having trouble storing the values in a global scope. Here is the code:

```
var GeoLoco = React.createClass({
    lat: 0,
    long: 0,
    handler: function(position) {
            this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
            this.long = position.coords.longitude;
            console.log("Lat,Long: "+this.lat+","+this.long);
    },
    render: function() {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.handler);
            return <p>Lat,Long: {this.lat},{this.long}</p>;
    }
});
```

`console.log` displays the location data, but `this.lat` and `this.long` render as 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if your variable's values changed, you have to re-render your component to update what you're seeing.
The component's `state` does it for you.

[More information here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html)

> By default, when your component's state or props change, your component will re-render.

So :

```
var GeoLoco = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {lat: 0, long: 0};
  },
  handler: function(position) {
    this.setState({
      lat: position.coords.latitude,
      long: position.coords.longitude
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    // If this.state.lat is not equal to 0, do not call again getCurrentPosition()
    if (!this.state.lat)
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.handler);
    return <p>Lat,Long: {this.state.lat},{this.state.long}</p>;
  }
});
```

If you don't want to use `state`, you can call `forceUpdate()` at the end of your handler method.

```
handler: function(position) {
  this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
  this.long = position.coords.longitude;
  console.log("Lat,Long: "+this.lat+","+this.long);
  this.forceUpdate();
},
```

Comment: Knew it was a timing issue. Thank you so much `this.forceUpdate()` did the trick.